# In Django, the | operator is creating duplicates when I merge two querysets together

Tags: python, django

This is a really strange thing, because I understand the | operator is supposed to create a union of two querysets without duplicating objects. I'm trying to perform a query search, and getting sets of objects to display on the page. One of these sets are for posts.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
if query:
        block_list = Block.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(tags__slug__icontains=query))
        user_list = CustomUser.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=query) | 
                    Q(last_name__icontains=query) | Q(username__icontains=query))
        post_list = Post.objects.filter(Q(tags__slug__icontains=query))
        post_list_by_title = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
        print(post_list)
        print(post_list_by_title)
        print(post_list | post_list_by_title)
```

Here is the outcome of the three print commands in cmd.

```
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet [<Post: Post1>]>
<QuerySet [<Post: Post1>, <Post: Post1>, <Post: Post1>]>
```

In case you're wondering why I split the post_list by tag and post_list by title, I originally had:

```
post_list = Post.objects.filter(Q(tags__slug__icontains=query) | Q(title__icontains=query))
```

But when I printed post_list, it still came out to be:

```
<QuerySet [<Post: Post1>, <Post: Post1>, <Post: Post1>]>
```

all the same. Do you have any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **`OR`** ing the **`Q`** objects and later call [**`distinct()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) method,

```
qs_without_dup = Post.objects.filter(Q(tags__slug__icontains=query)|Q(title__icontains=query)).distinct()
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much, though I am still confused about the union causing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.distinct()` after `.filter` to remove duplicates in your query itself, but then also it will fetch 2 same (before 3)  objects for which you can use distinct in your `(post_list | post_list_by_title)`